# Removing A specific Tag in VCF file using C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, tags, vcf-vcard

I have a very large number of records in VCF file, the issue is When Phone Exports, It adds File with Tag name ."PHOTO", when I am importing this VCF file into other phone, It appends that information into name fields, causing too long and large Contact Name,
One thing I was doing was with manual find and delete, but in a file having 25000+ lines its so difficult,

I am thinking to move with REGX and remove, But there also issues, for some records, PHOTO Tag is the Last Record then END:VCARD at some points ITS, TEL;..

Here is the sample I have taken, Just one Clue, then Rest I will try at my own.

```
public string RemoveBlockComments(string InputString)
{
   string strRegex = @"<regx>";
   RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
   Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
   return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, "");
}
```

Here is Test data:

```
PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=B:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMoHBwYIDAoMDAsK
CwsNDhIQDQ4KL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
BhJB
TEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789
```

I want to remove All from PHOTO to BhJb(before Tel)

Possible Formats.

- PHOTO....
- Tel;
- PHOTO....
- EMAIL;
- PHOTO....
- END:VCARD

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking for something like this: [`(?s)^.*(?=\bTEL\b)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)%5e.*(%3f%3d%5cbTEL%5cb)&i=PHOTO%3bTYPE%3dPNG%3bENCODING%3dB%3a%2f9j%2f4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2f2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMoHBwYIDAoMDAsK%0d%0aCwsNDhIQDQ4KL%2f8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx%0d%0aBhJB%0d%0aTEL%3bTYPE%3dCELL%3a123456789%0d%0a&r=) (do not use `RegexOptions.Multiline`!) and only `TEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789` will be left then. You can add alternatives to the lookahead: `(?=\b(?:TEL|EMAIL|END:VCARD)\b)`...

Comment: Ohh right then, but it should start with PHOTO<any characters and end with> TEL|EMAIL|END ? Right?

Comment: Yes, it can, please check [`(?s)^PHOTO\b.*(?=\b(?:TEL|EMAIL|END:VCARD)\b)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fs)%5ePHOTO%5cb.*(%3f%3d%5cb(%3f%3aTEL%7cEMAIL%7cEND%3aVCARD)%5cb)&i=PHOTO%3bTYPE%3dPNG%3bENCODING%3dB%3a%2f9j%2f4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2f2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMoHBwYIDAoMDAsK%0d%0aCwsNDhIQDQ4KL%2f8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx%0d%0aBhJB%0d%0aTEL%3bTYPE%3dCELL%3a123456789%0d%0a&r=). Well, if you have *multiple blocks* of such texts that you want to process with regex you will need multiline option, too. However, it is not a good idea to process complex blocks with regex only.

Comment: Can you paste the removed line from function?

Comment: Do you mean capture the text to later use somewhere else? You'd need to use `Regex.Match` with [`(?ms)^(PHOTO\b.*?)(?=\b(?:TEL|EMAIL|END:VCARD)\b)`](http://goo.gl/qzIMrp). The text is accessible via `Regex.Match(txt).Groups[1].Value`. Does it all make sense and answer your question?

Comment: @stribizhev : I have this code but its not working: **private static String ReFormat(String str)
        {
            //Use named capturing groups to make life easier
            //var pattern = "(?s)^PHOTO\b.*(?=\b(?:TEL|EMAIL|END)\b)";

            string pattern = "(?s)^PHOTO\b.*(?=\b(?:TEL|EMAIL|END)\b)";
            string replacement = "";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
            string result = rgx.Replace(str, replacement);

            return Regex.Replace(str, pattern, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82491/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-daredevil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our chat discussion, it seems that you need to do 2 things:

- Get the text after the `TEL`, `EMAIL`, `END` (or anything else you may have on the list of valid values there)
- Get the part before that starts with `PHOTO`.

You can get the 2 values easily with your [updated method](https://ideone.com/ixRTcd):

```
private static String ReFormat(String str, out String removed) 
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?msi)(?<removed>PHOTO\b.*?)(?=\b(?:TEL|EMAIL|END)\b)");
    removed = rgx.Match(str).Groups["removed"].Value;
    return str.Replace(removed, string.Empty); 
}
```

And in the caller:

```
string removed = string.Empty;
string rest = ReFormat("PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=B:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMoHBwYIDAoMDAsK\r\nCwsNDhIQDQ4KL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx\r\nBhJB\r\nTEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789", out removed);
```

Or I think you can use a method that returns a list of key-value pairs:

```
private static List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> ReFormat(String str) 
{
    return Regex.Matches(str, @"(?msi)(?<photo>PHOTO\b.*?)(?<tel>\b(?:TEL|EMAIL|END)\b.*?(?=\bPHOTO|$))").Cast<Match>().Select(p=> new KeyValuePair<String, String>(p.Groups["photo"].Value, p.Groups["tel"].Value)).ToList();
}
```

And then

```
var my_result = ReFormat("PHOTO;TYPE=PNG;ENCODING=B:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMoHBwYIDAoMDAsK\r\nCwsNDhIQDQ4KL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx\r\nBhJB\r\nTEL;TYPE=CELL:123456789");
var mres1 = ReFormat("PHOTO;..jkh ohfhlahflkhasf fhasof\r\nTel:886886\r\ndataPHOTO:.ljlljhkdsghdsgd\n\rEmail:abc@abc.com..");
```

[image]

[image]